# Is it possible to spy on or mock the value of a "behind-the-scenes" variable?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, sinon

Let's say I have code that modifies a variable which is not exposed to the user like this:

```
var model;

module.exports = {
  doSomething: function() {
    ...
    //at some point in the code, modify model
    if(/* something happened */) {
      model = '123';
    },
    doSomethingElse: function() {
      //use model in some way
    }
  }
};
```

If I later want to write a unit test to make sure that `model` was updated, but I do not have a getter for it, how can I test this? Is this possible to do with Karma/Jasmine/Sinon.js?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to check the model value directly because it's hidden in a closure.

You can still write tests for it though: Your "model" will make `doSomethingElse` behave differently. You can verify that it matches your expectations after calling `doSomething`. This way, you are also free refactor the internals of your module without changing the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

In general, testing private methods or properties is an antipattern. By making aspects of your implementation private, you're explicitly creating the freedom to change how those implementation details work in the future without changing your public API.

Therefore, in an ideal world, you should not (and in this case, you cannot) test the `model` value.

That said, we don't always live in an ideal world. So, there are some workarounds that you might consider if you really, really must test private properties and methods.

**First**, you could look for an environment variable, and export additional properties (by attaching them to the `exports`).

```
var model;
module.exports = {
  ...
}
if(process.env.ENV === 'TEST') {
  module.exports.model = model;
}
```

**Second**, you can use conventions instead of making things completely private. For example, a common convention is to prefix private entities with `_` to signify that they are not part of the public API. This can have varied levels of effectiveness depending on the audience that will consume your API.

**Third**, you could create accessors for your private variables, and check for the presence of a testing environment in some way (perhaps a global variable, an environment variable, or a variable injected into your module upon instantiation) that only allows access when the test environment is detected.

**Fourth**, you could allow an "inspector" object to be injected into your module (this object would only be present during testing). I have used this pattern with some success.

```
module.exports = function(spies) {
   ...
   spies = spies || {};
   var model = spies.model;
   ...
}
...
// instantiate the module in the test
var spies = {};
var mock = new Module(spies);
// do a thing
expect(spies.model).to.eql("foo");
```

**But really, you should reconsider your testing strategy and design.**